# Redux reducer: Add object to array on returning new state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I´m new with Redux and I´m trying to avoid doing the things in the wrong way.

I´m using redux-thunk. I have a function that makes the call to the API and depending on if there is an error or not it dispatches:
fetchUserOK(data) or fetchUserErr(data)

On my reducer file, when I´m switching if the case is

FETCH_USER_OK I do:

```
return action.payload;
```

FETCH_USER_ERR I do:

```
return [...state, { error: action.payload }];
```

I think return action.payload; is ok and I dont need to spread the previous state. Please, correct me if I´m wrong.
But, I do not have any clue if what I´m doing for error is right:

```
return [...state, { error: action.payload }];
```

The payload for OK would look like

```
[{id: 1, name: "Peter"}, {id: 2, name: "Kevin"}, {id: 3, name: "Paul"}]
```

The payload for ERR: string

```
404
```

Should I return the state (...state) ?
Should I wrap between {} the key:value?

I will appreciate advice.
I´m trying to avoid bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the reducer returns the update state when you do `{...state, anyfield: action.payload}` you are actually updating the state, this means that copy all fields from state and replace all field after first `,`. It is recommended to always update your state with [immutable update patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns) rather then doing `state.somefield = value` followed by `return state`.

So to answer your question. From what i understood your reducer MUST always return an update state so returning just `action.payload` is not the correct way to do it. You must always add existing state by ...state.

[UPDATE]

You can read [this](https://hackernoon.com/redux-lifecycle-8e93908af03a) article. It will tell you about redux cycle. Whatever return from the reducer will replace the previous state of the application so you always want to return updated state will all the fields rather then just action payload.